# Bash alias for apt-cache

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
apt-cache search "google chrome" | awk '{print $1}' | perl -pe '$_ = "\033[1;29m$_\033[0m" if($. % 2)'
```

So is there any option of making a bash alias out of it? It works but I don't have a clue of how to pass an argument to replace "google chrome" in this case. Or is there any simpler way of doing it?

Also:
Is there any way for showing an Architecture (apt-cache show) for each line? I was using gentoo previously and am always choosing hard way, I suppose...

Comment: What I basically want to do is to show packages names without their short description but with architecture and version info

Comment: Any particular reason you want an alias, as opposed to a script or a function?

Comment: Well... It could also be a script :) Don't know why I haven't thought of it.

Comment: You can make it a script by replacing `"google chrome"` with `"$1"`, adding `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, and making it executable

Comment: I think it won't work this way. Anyway... How to treat each line as a variable? I want to check verion for each package too...

Comment: But $@ would do instead

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a function using `"$@"` for your parameters:

```
search() {
  apt-cache search "$@" | awk '{print $1}' | perl -pe '$_ = "\033[1;29m$_\033[0m" if($. % 2)'
}
```

With this in your `.bashrc`, you can `search google chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-cache search $@ | awk '{print $1}' |
while read line; do apt-cache madison $line; done |
sed 's/^ *//' |
perl -pe '$_ = "\e[34m$_\e[39m" if($.%2==1)' ;
echo -e "\e[49m"
```

That's what I've made. And it actually works :x

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
apt-cache search "$1" | 
 awk '{ print (NR%2) ? "\033[1;29m-> " $1 "\033[0m" : "-> " $1 ; 
        system ("apt-cache show " $1 "| egrep  \"^Package|^Version|^Architecture\"") 
      }'
```

I've also tried to accommodate your second request too (`apt-cache show` for each line) in the code above. Modify it if needed.